# Filtrar expresiones en consulta SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy intentado realizar una consulta en SQL Developer (Oracle) sobre varias tablas. En la cual necesito comparar el resultado de expresión si es Mayor o Igual (x >= 0) o si es Menor:

**`X >= 0 => Resultado: 'S' ; X < 0 => Resultado: 'N'`**

Y también necesito poner un rango de valores sobre una expresión es decir:

**`x > 100 => Resultado: 100 ; x < 0 => Resultado 0 ; 0 =< x =< 100 => Resultado: X`**

Intenté hacerlo por medio de CASE Expressions pero no he recibido el resultado esperado
La consulta en cuestión es la siguiente:

```
    SELECT cns.DIA,
SUM(vs.NETO),
    SUM(cns.GASTO),
    SUM(t.ASIG),
        SUM(cns.GASTO)-(SUM(t.ASIG)/SUM(vs.NETO) AS X,
        CASE SUM(cns.GASTO)-(SUM(t.ASIG) + SUM(vs.NETO)) WHEN 0 THEN 'S'
        ELSE 'N' END AS USO
    FROM T1.CONSUMO cns,
         T2.VOLSERV vs,
         T3.TRANS t;
```

**RESULTADO OBTENIDO**

```
DIA         NETO       GASTO    ASIG   USO
19/08/2017  70000      115080   50000   N
```

Tendría que recibir una 'S' ya que gastó más de la cuenta.

Un saludo.-

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que lo que quieres hacer es lo siguiente:

```
SQL> select case when 1 >= 0 then 'S' else 'N' end from dual;

C
-
S
```

Entonces tendrias que cambiar tu SQL:

```
SELECT cns.DIA,
SUM(vs.NETO),
    SUM(cns.GASTO),
    SUM(t.ASIG),
        SUM(cns.GASTO)-(SUM(t.ASIG)/SUM(vs.NETO) AS X,
        CASE WHEN SUM(cns.GASTO)-(SUM(t.ASIG) + SUM(vs.NETO)) => 0 THEN 'S'
        ELSE 'N' END AS USO
    FROM T1.CONSUMO cns,
         T2.VOLSERV vs,
         T3.TRANS t;
```

Saludos